# Change default CPU affinity

Tags: linux, cpu, affinity

I would like to know whether it's possible the default affinity for linux processes. The default value is ~0 (truncated to the number of CPUs available) but I'd like to be able to set it for all the process of the system. It would be also nice to do this at boot time so I could effectively prevent any process from using certain CPUs (unless explicitely set by a syscall).

Thanks!
David

Comment: This is a system admin question, try unix.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com.

Comment: On the shell or in a C program ?

Comment: Use `taskset` to launch a new shell with the affinity you want. All programs launched by that shell will have the same affinity.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From  C program:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>

int sched_setaffinity(pid_t pid, size_t cpusetsize, cpu_set_t *mask);
```

see `man sched_setaffinity` for further information.

From the shell:

```
taskset <mask> <command> <args>
```

or

```
taskset -p <pid> <mask>
```

where `<mask>` is, for example, `0x00000001` for the first CPU.